# Examples for the fact that a pullback of an epimorphism is not necessarily an epimorphism.

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading in Borceux' book [Basic Category Theory](https://books.google.be/books?id=YfzImoopB-IC&pg=PA52&dq=pullback%20epimorphisms%20category%20theory&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig6Oub_frMAhUDLsAKHRfxA1EQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=pullback%20epimorphisms%20category%20theory&f=false) about pullbacks. It turns out that the pullback of an epimorphism is not necessarily an epimorphism. On the linked page, Borceux gives a counterexample in the category **Haus**.

I was wondering whether there also exist easy counterexamples in **Ring**, the category of commutative rings with a 1 element (or in **Grp**, **Rng**, etc.). I have been playing around with the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, which is an epimorphism, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is supposed to be an answer to a tiny fraction of your question: In $\mathsf{Grp}$ epis *are* stable under pullbacks (therefore you can stop searching for a counterexample there).

This is because [in $\mathsf{Grp}$ every epi is regular](https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/epimorphisms+in+the+category+of+groups) and regular epis are stable under taking pullbacks, because $\mathsf{Grp}$ (and more generally every category of universal algebras) is a regular category.

The same applies for example to $\mathsf{Set}$ and to every abelian category, in particular $R\mathsf{Mod}$ for every ring $R$.

Actually, in a (concrete) category of universal algebras $(\mathcal{A}, U : \mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Set})$ a morphism is a regular epi if and only, if it is surjective (its underlying function is surjective). We can conclude, that the following are equivalent for $\mathcal{A}$:

- every epi is regular ("epi $=$ regular epi")
- every epi is surjective ("epi $=$ surjective")
- $\mathcal{A}$ is balanced ("mono & epi $\Rightarrow$ iso")

Hence, every concrete "algebraic" category satisfying one of the equivalent conditions above is off the table for counterexamples (again: regular epis are stable under pullbacks in a regular category)

Comment: Saying "epis are stable under taking pullbacks because Grp is a regular category" is a little vacuous...

Comment: @MorganRogers Nonetheless, the point of such a statement is to establish that the claim is related to the notion of "regular category" which one can now search for.

Answer (score 8):

An example in $\mathsf{Ring}$ is the inclusion $\mathbb{C}[t]\to\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$, which is an epimorphism, but whose pullback along $\mathbb{C}[t^{-1}]\to\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ is $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}[t^{-1}]$, which is not an epimorphism.

However, every pullback of $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism. There's a proof in the answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264156/stable-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings).

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field,  consider the category of quasi affine varieties and $U$ a Zariski open subset  of $k^n$, such that $U=k^n-Z(f)$ where $f$ is a polynomial function. The imbedding $i:U\rightarrow k^n$ is an epimorphism, consider the embedding $j:V(f)\rightarrow k^n$, the pullback of $j:V(f)\rightarrow k^n$ is the $\phi\rightarrow V(f)$ is not an epimorphism.