# Is there a functor from the category of commutative rings that is faithful but not conservative?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

The category of commutative rings is not balanced (the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is monic and epic but not an isomorphism).

So, is there a category $C$ and a functor $\mathbf{CRing} \to C$ that is faithful but not conservative (isomorphism-reflecting)? If so, then there should be such a functor that maps the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ to an isomorphism.

The functor $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} -:\mathbf{CRing} \to \mathbf{CRing}$ will not work, as that functor is neither faithful nor conservative. Indeed, if $R$ is any (commutative) ring of nonzero characteristic, the tensor products $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (R \times R)$ and $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ vanish, and so both projection maps $R \times R \to R$ are mapped to the trivial map $0 \to 0$.

If the functor really does exist, then it must be "pathological" in some sense. In particular, it cannot be a finite-coproduct-preserving functor (as if it were finite-coproduct-preserving, then it must also map $\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \to \mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ to an isomorphism for any commutative ring $R$, and thus the functor must collapse all commutative rings of nonzero characteristic, destroying both faithfulness and conservativity).

The answer to [Stable epimorphisms of commutative rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264156/stable-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings) suggests the following:

Let $W$ be the class of all monic epimorphisms in $\mathbf{CRing}$ that are preserved by pullback. Then, the answer there shows that the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ belongs to $W$. Also, one could easily verify that $W$ meets the requirements for having a [calculus of right fractions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+fractions). Hence, one could form the category of fractions $\mathbf{CRing}[W^{-1}]$.

One could then ask whether the localization functor $\mathbf{CRing} \to \mathbf{CRing}[W^{-1}]$ is faithful. If so, then that would answer the question.

Comment: Will any faithful functor (to any category) do? Why not the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$? Edit: D'oh, I just realised you want the inclusion map itself to be an isomorphism (and don't merely want the images of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ to be isomorphic via a possibly different map). But I'll leave this comment here so nobody else makes the same mistake.

Comment: @M.Vinay I made the same mistake in my (now deleted) answer. Faithful means that if $F(f)$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ is an isomorphism. The forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$ is not conservative, because any bijective homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Just realised that myself! I was only thinking that the images of these objects need to be isomorphic, and forgot that OP wants the inclusion map itself to be an isomorphism.

Comment: To Geoffrey Trang: I don't understand why you say that if there is a faithful but not conservative functor out of $\mathsf{CRing}$, then there should be one that maps the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$ to an isomorphism. Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: What happens if you localize the category of rings at the class of monic epimorphisms?

Comment: I have an intuition that given any starting category $C$, freely adding inverses to all mono-epis is faithful. However, even if this is true, you won’t necessary get a locally small category of when doing this to a large but locally small category.

Comment: Since any functor factors through the localization (strictly if you like) and being faithful is cancellative, the localization must be an example if there are any examples. @MarkSaving because we're localizing at a *set* of maps there's no concern about non local smallness, right? Edit: oops, I was thinking of just inverting $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ and didn't realize you'd proposed inverting all balanced maps

Comment: A failed attempt, which will hopefully save the next person some time: The pseudofunctor sending a ring $R$ to its category of modules $\mathsf{Mod}_R$ (and sending a ring hom $R \to S$ to the [restriction of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Restriction_of_scalars)) is faithful (probably? I haven't thought very hard about it), I thought this was likely to not be conservative (in some bicategorical sense) since there are interesting [morita equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence) in the world (at least for noncommutative rings)...

Comment: ... Unfortunately, it [looks like](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/morita-equivalence-and-the-bicategory-of-bimodules/) if restriction of scalars along $f$ is a morita equivalence, then $f$ must have been an isomorphism all along! So (surprisingly, for me) this actually satisfies a bicategorical conservativity too!

Comment: How could the localisation (even at just $\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow \mathbb Q$) possibly be faithful? Doesn't this map every homomorphism on $\mathbb Z$ with a non-trivial kernel to the zero morphism? (Or am I just tired?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happens when you localize at the class $W$ described in the
OP, but if you just adjoin an inverse to the inclusion
$s:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ then I think that works. The fact that $\mathbb{Z}$
is an initial object in the category of rings makes it relatively easy to figure
out what's going on, even without a calculus of fractions.

In principle, you need to consider morphisms $R\to S$ in
$\mathbf{CRing}[s^{-1}]$ that are given by arbitrarily long expressions
$$\alpha s^{-1}\gamma_{1} s^{-1 }\gamma_{2}s^{-1}\dots s^{-1}\gamma_{n}s^{-1}\beta$$
where $\alpha:\mathbb{Z}\to S$, $\gamma_{i}:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ and
$\beta:R\to\mathbb{Q}$ are ring homomorphisms. But every $\gamma_{i}$ must be
equal to $s$, so this simplifies to
$$\alpha s^{-1}\beta.$$ So every morphism $R\to S$ in $\mathbf{CRing}[s^{-1}]$ is
represented by an expression $\alpha s^{-1}\beta$ or by a ring homomorphism
$\gamma:R\to S$.

If $\alpha=\alpha's$ for some ring homomorphism $\alpha':\mathbb{Q}\to S$ then
$\alpha s^{-1}\beta=\alpha'\beta$ as morphisms $R\to S$, and if
$\beta=s\beta'$ for some ring homomorphism $\beta':R\to\mathbb{Z}$ then $\alpha
s^{-1}\beta=\alpha\beta'$.

With the previous discussion as motivation, let's try to define a category
$\mathbf{C}$.

The objects of $\mathbf{C}$ will be commutative rings.

For rings $R$ and $S$, a "pre-morphism" $R\to S$ will be a ring homomorphism
$R\to S$ or an expression $\alpha s^{-1}\beta$, where $\alpha:\mathbb{Z}\to S$
and $\beta:R\to\mathbb{Q}$ are ring homomorphisms.

Say that a pre-morphism "contracts" to a ring homomorphism $\gamma:R\to S$ if
it is equal to $\gamma$ or it is equal to $(\alpha's)s^{-1}\beta$ where
$\gamma=\alpha'\beta$, or to $\alpha s^{-1}(s\beta')$, where
$\gamma=\alpha\beta'$.

Note that since $s$ is monic and epic, $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ above are
uniquely determined, if they exist, and if $\alpha=\alpha's$ and
$\beta=s\beta'$, then both ways of contracting $\alpha s^{-1}\beta$ lead to
$\alpha's\beta'$, so a pre-morphism can not contract to more than one ring
homomorphism.

Now define a morphism to be an equivalence class of pre-morphisms, where two
pre-morphisms are equivalent if they are equal or if they both contract to the
same ring homomorphism.

Define composition by

- $[\gamma][\delta]=[\gamma\delta]$
- $[\gamma][\alpha s^{-1}\beta]=[(\gamma\alpha)s^{-1}\beta]$
- $[\alpha s^{-1}\beta][\gamma]=[\alpha s^{-1}(\beta\gamma)]$
- $[\alpha_{1} s^{-1}\beta_{1}][\alpha_{2}s^{-1}\beta_{2}]
    =[\alpha_{1}s^{-1}\beta_{2}]$

wherever domains and codomains match up. (Note that in the last case,
$\beta_{1}\alpha_{2}$ must be equal to $s$.) It is straightforward to check that
this composition is well defined.

An easy but tedious calculation shows that composition is associative, and
clearly $[\operatorname{id}_{R}]$ is an identity morphism for the ring $R$, so
$\mathbf{C}$ is a category.

The functor $\mathbf{CRing}\to\mathbf{C}$ that is the identity on objects and
that sends $\gamma$ to $[\gamma]$ is faithful and sends $s$ to an isomorphism with inverse $[\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}s^{-1}\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Q}}]$.